# how to dynamically add hubsection inside Hub control in window store

Tags: windows-store-apps

We want to dynamically bind number of Hub Sections based on number of items in a collection. As of now we are doing in Code behind. I want to do in XAML directly without any code behind. Has any1 performed HubSection dynamically based number of items in collection

Comment: Did you already got a solution for this? I'm looking for something similar.